# Show date and time on GUVCViewer recordings?

Tags: 12.04, video, webcam

I am using GUVCViewer to record video using my webcam.  How do I display the current date time on the video which is being recorded?

Comment: Check this Question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/428500/how-to-add-time-stamp-when-using-ffmpeg-webcan-recording/428501#428501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GUVCViewer** doesn't support this feature , why you don't try ffmpeg video recording , it support time stamp when recording your webcam .