# How to Add Time stamp when using ffmpeg Video Recorder?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any option , that let a user record a video with a **time stamp** .

I use many web-cam recording and i didn't found this option .

Program i used **Guvcview** , **Cheese** .

**Any Help ?**